# Lists and While loops

Tags: python, list, function, while-loop

I am having issues getting my code to not accept numbers higher than the maximum. When I put something higher than 101 it just says "Too big, try again", but it wont let me try again. It takes me out of the loop and I have to restart the function to try again. When input a number smaller than 0 it works perfectly.

```
def addGrade(grade_list):
    myGrades = -1
    while 0 > myGrades < 101:
        myGrades = int(input('Enter a number between 0 and 100: '))
        if myGrades < 0:
            print('Too small, try again')
        if myGrades > 101:
            print('Too big, try again')
    grade_list.append(myGrades)
    print(grade_list)
    return myGrades
```

Comment: Please see [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) for tips on formatting your posts including your code.

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies within your while loop:

while 0 > myGrades < 101:

must be:

```
while 0 < myGrades and myGrades < 101:
```

here's your code working if you enter 1337 it gets out of the function

```
def addGrade(grade_list):
    myGrades = -1 
    while True:
        myGrades = int(input('Enter a number between 0 and 100: ')) 
        if myGrades == 1337:
            break
        if myGrades < 0:
            print('Too small, try again') 
            continue
        if myGrades > 101:
            print('Too big, try again') 
            continue
        grade_list.append(myGrades) 
        print(grade_list) 
    return myGrades
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as already said the while condition is not correct. That's the way I would write it:

```
my_grade = 0
while not (0 < my_grade < 101):
    my_grade = int(input('Enter number: '))
print 'Ok this is a good value {}'.format(my_grade)
```